# Spring Boot - Cannot configure CORS Options policy

Tags: spring-boot, cors

I have a Spring Boot rest api server and i'm trying to connect to it via a Vue.js application

This is how i configured my Spring Boot Security

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http.

    .....

    .cors()

  }

     @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("/**"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization", "content-type", "x-auth-token"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

When i try to access an authorization token from the client i get a 403 error on the OPTIONS request with this error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8081/oauth/token' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I do not know what else should I set up

Comment: The problem isn’t your CORS configuration. The problem is that your server is responding with a 403 to for OPTIONS requests to `http://localhost:8081/oauth/token`. You need to configure that server to instead respond to OPTIONS request for that URL with a 200 OK.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should have `"*"` instead of `"/**"` in `setAllowedOrigins` there.

Also correct way to configure CORS AFAIK would be this:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("authorization", "content-type", "x-auth-token")
                .exposedHeaders("x-auth-token");
    }
}
```

See also [CorsRegistration javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/CorsRegistration.html) and [Setting up CORS in Spring Boot tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors)